# mongodb aggregate drop subfield using $unset

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have documents looks like this, and I want to drop `info.$time` field using `$unset` operator.

```json
{
  "id": 1234,
  "info": {
    "msg": "hello world",
    "$time": Timestamp(1610515499)
  }
}
```

I've tried

```
db.aggregate([
  { $unset: [ "info.$time" ] },
  // next stage
])
```

but this gives error.

```
"errmsg" : "Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath
field names may not start with '$'."
```

I also tried just `"info.time"` but this doesn't actually drop the field.

Comment: You want to remove that field from collection permanently? or you just need to remove from result only?

Comment: see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14466?focusedCommentId=1598429&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1598429

Comment: See [Restrictions on Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#limit-restrictions-on-field-names). It is a very bad idea to have field names starting with dollar `$` sign - although it might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments fields starting with $ are unsupported.

If you are using a driver rather than MongoDB shell you should receive an error when you try inserting such data:

```rb
irb(main):006:0> a['foo'].insert_one({foo:{'$bar'=>1}})
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/operation/shared/sessions_supported.rb:226:in `tap'
       15: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/operation/shared/sessions_supported.rb:231:in `block in build_message'
       14: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/msg.rb:152:in `serialize'
       13: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:192:in `serialize'
       12: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:331:in `serialize_fields'
       11: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:331:in `each'
       10: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:343:in `block in serialize_fields'
        9: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:187:in `serialize'
        8: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:187:in `each'
        7: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:194:in `block in serialize'
        6: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:316:in `serialize'
        5: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:316:in `each'
        4: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:317:in `block in serialize'
        3: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:358:in `serialize'
        2: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/hash.rb:42:in `to_bson'
        1: from /home/w/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/hash.rb:42:in `put_hash'
BSON::String::IllegalKey ('$bar' is an illegal key in MongoDB. Keys may not start with '$' or contain a '.'.)
```